# PowerPoint Print Page Count

Tags: c#, printing, count, powerpoint

I am trying to obtain the number of pages that are expected to be printed when using the PowerPoint Interop to print a whole document(ranges do not apply).

**To be more specific I am seeking to obtain the number of pages that Print Preview indicates**(*since this takes into account all formating options*).

for example:  I have a 48 slide document but when it prints it produces 56 images.

I am currently calling the Printout() method with no parameters.

Comment: PowerPoint prints one sheet per slide.  I don't see how you could get 56 images (sheets, do you mean?) from a 48 slide presentation, unless you're printing notes pages that have been auto-continued because of heavy notes text, or you're looking at a slide show that displays 48 out of 56 slides because some of the slides are hidden.  Or possibly that you're seeing page numbers that go to 56 but only 48 actual sheets are printing?  PPT lets the user change the starting page number, so if it were set to something other than 1, you'd get page numbers that don't match the number of printed sheets.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg, Essentially what I am looking to obtain is the Number of pages shown in Print Preview (which shows that it will print 56 pages). Within code, I apply various formating settings, so printing halfpage slides with notes and print comments as a seperate page could all be applied, in any combination.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there is no way of getting that number you seek directly. The printing is handled by the driver, so vba is probably unaware of it.

A cumbersome solution could be to generate an xps-file temporarily and count its pages. Not exactly elegant though. Another way would be to determine the number of pages each slide has on a per-slide basis - place an indicator as a property of the slide on each - and in a second step count them by incrementing over slides. You may find this interesting: http://officeone.mvps.org/vba/ppt_tags.html

Comment: Printing is a conversation between the app and the driver.  VBA can set up the app's print parameters, but doesn't know what the result will be.  Similar to the XPS idea (and possibly simpler) would be to print to a Postscript driver set to File.  Within the last few lines of the file, you'll see a PS comment:  %%Pages: XX   XX is your answer.  For the XPS file, you'd have to crack it open (it's a zip).  Whatever you do, be careful setting the XPS driver to print to file.  I did that on two systems and now PPT won't print to XPS on either of them.

Comment: for excels you can get the value of the pages to be printed in the Pagesetup portion of the api..(per worksheet of the workbook)... going to go dig throught he xps and see if that produces what i am looking for.

Comment: The xps file idea was not able to give me the correct amount pages (after formating is applied) because it captures the file as is.